# Tkinter color-chooser windows VS. linux

Tags: python, tkinter, colors

Can anyone explain, why i get different results with this Code on linux and windows. On windows its a complete color picker and on Linux its Crap. 
Both Tkinter Modules are Version(8.6)

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.colorchooser import *
def getColor():
    color = askcolor() 
    print color
Button(text='Select Color', command=getColor).pack()
mainloop()
```

[Windows Example](https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-B25-v85BJok/UDqFpJEiDoI/AAAAAAAABL8/JO-r7LkRkFg/s1600/clrpick_3.PNG)

[Linux Example](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/python-26-graphics/9781849513845/graphics/3845_05_07.jpg)

Comment: Can you tell us which versions of tkinter you are using in each case?

Comment: What makes you think it's bad on Linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the comments in the source code of `colorchooser.py`:

```
  # this module provides an interface to the native color dialogue
  # available in Tk 4.2 and newer.
```

You are seeing a native dialog from underlying OS, not a dialog built the usual tkinter way.

Comment: Actually, `tkinter` doesn't use a native dialog on Linux; it builds it itself.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to the question of why it's different on different platforms is that on both windows and the mac, the dialogs are provided by the underlying OS. On linux, tkinter must draw the dialog itself.